# cannot unmarshal received request using JAXB

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, unmarshalling

I defined all required elements but the code can not parse server response. I changed  `@XmlSeeAlso({ Artist.class, Venue.class })` to  `@XmlSeeAlso({Venue.class })` but it did not help.

I also added a `package-info.java` file.

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://ticketmaster.productserve.com/v2/soap.php",
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED
)
package com.myproject.tickets.ticketmaster;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

**Error**

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not 
unmarshal to [class com.myproject.tickets.ticketmaster.Data]: unexpected 
element (uri:"", local:"data"). Expected elements are 
 <{http://ticketmaster.productserve.com/v2/soap.php}artist>, 
 <{http://ticketmaster.productserve.com/v2/soap.php}data>,
 <{http://ticketmaster.productserve.com/v2/soap.php}details>,
 <{http://ticketmaster.productserve.com/v2/soap.php}results>,
 <{http://ticketmaster.productserve.com/v2/soap.php}venue>; nested exception 
  is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", 
  local:"data"). Expected elements are 
  <{http://ticketmaster.productserve.com/v2/soap.php}artist>,
  <{http://ticketmaster.productserve.com/v2/soap.php}data>,
  <{http://ticketmaster.productserve.com/v2/soap.php}details>,
  <{http://ticketmaster.productserve.com/v2/soap.php}results>,
  <{http://ticketmaster.productserve.com/v2/soap.php}venue>
```

**Response**

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>    
   <data>
   <details>
      <totalResults></totalResults>
      <totalPages></totalPages>
      <currentPage></currentPage>
      <resultsPerPage></resultsPerPage>
   </details>
   <results>
       <eventId></eventId>  
       <ticketmasterEventId></ticketmasterEventId>   
       <status></status>
       <name></name>
       <url></url>
       <eventDate></eventDate>
       <onSaleDate></onSaleDate>
       <preSaleDate></preSaleDate>
       <category></category>
       <categoryId></categoryId>
       <parentCategory></parentCategory>
       <parentCategoryId></parentCategoryId>
       <minPrice></minPrice>
       <maxPrice></maxPrice>
       <artists>
          <artistId></artistId>
          <ticketmasterArtistId></ticketmasterArtistId>
          <name></name>
          <url></url>
          <imageUrl></imageUrl>
          <category></category>
          <categoryId></categoryId>
          <parentCategory></parentCategory>       
          <parentCategoryId></parentCategoryId>
       </artists>
       <venue>
          <venueId></venueId>
          <ticketmasterVenueId></ticketmasterVenueId>
          <name></name>
          <street></street>
          <city></city>
          <country></country>
          <postcode></postcode>
          <url></url>
          <imageUrl></imageUrl>
          <state/>
        </venue>
    </results>`    
    <results>
       .....
    </results>
    </data>
```

**Data**

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Data {
    @XmlElement
    Details details;
    @XmlElement
    List<Results> results;

    public Data() {
        super();
        this.results = new ArrayList<Results>();
    }
```

**Details**

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Details {
    @XmlElement
    private int totalResults;
    @XmlElement
    private int totalPages;
    @XmlElement
    private int currentPage;
    @XmlElement
    private int resultsPerPage;
```

**Results**

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlSeeAlso({ Artist.class, Venue.class })
public class Results {
    @XmlElement
    private long eventId;
    @XmlElement
    private String ticketmasterEventId;
    @XmlElement
    private String status;
    @XmlElement
    private String name;
    @XmlElement
    private String url;
    @XmlElement
    private String eventDate;
    @XmlElement
    private String onSaleDate;
    @XmlElement
    private String preSaleDate;
    @XmlElement
    private int categoyId;
    @XmlElement
    private String parentCategory;
    @XmlElement
    private int parentCategoryId;
    @XmlElement
    private Double minPrice;
    @XmlElement
    private Double maxPrice;
    @XmlElement(name = "Artists")
    private List<Artist> artists;
    @XmlElement
    private Venue venue;

    public Results() {
        super();
        this.artists = new ArrayList<Artist>();
    }
```

**Artist**

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Artist {
    @XmlElement
    private long artistId;
    @XmlElement
    private long ticketMasterArtistId;
    @XmlElement
    private String name;
    @XmlElement
    private String url;
    @XmlElement
    private String imageUrl;
    @XmlElement
    private String category;
    @XmlElement
    private int categoryId;
    @XmlElement
    private String parentCategory;
    @XmlElement
    private int parentCategoryId;
```

Comment: `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` remove this annotation

Comment: @Srinivasu why should I remove it? also from which class?

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue with the posted code. Can you post the actual XML? I am assuming `http://ticketmaster.productserve.com/v2/soap.php` is part of the response being parsed.

Comment: @manish I cannot post actual XML it is lengthy. address you mentioned is not in the response.

Comment: Then unfortunately it becomes a debugging problem that only you can resolve because the problem cannot be reproduced generically.

Comment: Maybe post this up github and point to that.

Comment: do not you need the structure of response xml? thats included in the question. what else is required?

Comment: You forgot the namespace in the XML file. Should be something like `<data xmlns="http://ticketmaster.productserve.com/v2/soap.php">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your unmarshaller expect an element with a namespace, while your XML doesn't have any.

For solving your problem, either :

- Put a namespace in your XML (xmlns="http://ticketmaster.productserve.com/v2/soap.php" attribute in your root element)
- Remove the namespace attribute from your @XmlSchema annotation